# How to structure solution for client server in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, client-server

I am new to networking and I am trying to make a basic client and server app.
I would like to know how I can structure my solution in visual studio for this.

What I have now is two projects - one for the client, one for the server. However, both the client and server use code from certain source files that are 'shared' if you would. Common purpose functions, etc.

Since both applications will need this code compiled, do I need to copy these source files in both the client and server project, or is there another, perhaps better way?

Comment: Create a third project, a static library. Put common code there. Go to `Project > Project Dependencies`, make the two other projects depend on this library one.